# Quisiera que se muestre solo la hora y minuto

Tags: angular, firebase, typescript, ionic, google-maps

> Quisiera que se muestre la hora y minuto exceptuando los segundos en la variable start_hour y final_hora. Por ejemplo: 17:00 en lugar de 17:00:30

```
const infoWindow1 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: 
    "<ion-row>" +
      "<ion-col>" +
        "<h6 style='font-weight: bold'; width: 100%;>" + tittle + "</h6>" +
      "</ion-col>" +
    "</ion-row>" +
    "<ion-row>" +  
      "<ion-col size='3'>" +
        "<p style='font-weight: bold;'>Lugar:</p>" +
      "</ion-col>" +
      "<ion-col size='9'>" +
        "<p>" + ubicacion + "</p>" +
      "</ion-col>" +
    "</ion-row>" +
    "<ion-row>" +
      "<ion-col size='3'>" +
        "<p style='font-weight: bold'>Hora: </p>" +
      "</ion-col>" +
      "<ion-col size='9'>" +
        "<p>" + starthour.split('T')[1].split('.')[0] + ' - ' + finalhour.split('T')[1].split('.')[0] + "</p>" +
      "</ion-col>" +
    "</ion-row>",
    });
```

Comment: En que formato esta actualmente?

Comment: Hay una libreria llamado moment que te ayuda a formatear todo tipo de fechas :D! https://momentjs.com/ espero te ayude :)

Comment: Gracias fue de buena ayuda tu respuesta :D

Answer (score 0):

Si estoy interpretando bien tu código, la hora te llega en formato ISO, incluyendo la parte de la fecha que es descartada en la línea:

```
"<p>" + starthour.split('T')[1].split('.')[0] + ' - ' + finalhour.split('T')[1].split('.')[0] + "</p>" +
```

Una manera sencilla de quitar los segundos sería sustituir la línea anterior por la siguiente:

```
"<p>" + starthour.split('T')[1].substring(0,5) + ' - ' + finalhour.split('T')[1].substring(0,5) + "</p>" +
```

La solución asume que la fecha y hora llega en un formato ISO del tipo: `2020-02-09T22:33:45.000`